# Entity Framework - How not to run CollectionChanged When loading the collection from the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the class below:

```
public class Orcamento
{
    public Orcamento()
    {
        Produtos = new ObservableCollection<Produto>();
        Produtos.CollectionChanged += ProdutosCollectionChanged;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Produto> Produtos { get; private set; }

    private void ProdutosCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Some process here that should not be run if it is being loaded from the database
    }

}
```

When I seek the Budget class in the database, the CollectionChanged event runs. Note the code below:

```
using (var contexto = new Contexto())
{

    Orcamento orcamento = contexto.Orcamentos.OrderByDescending(o => o.Id)
        .Include(x => x.Produtos)
        .FirstOrDefault();
    //More some code above...
}
```

Question: How do I know when the collection was modified by the user or when it was modified by loading the database, since only want the event to be triggered when the collection is modified by the user?

Comment: For which purposes do you use ObservableCollection? M.b. it is easier to change it to another type of collection?

Answer (score 0):

Add a Bool field in the Orcamento class and when changing value from database make the bool field to true. Check the bool value in  ProdutosCollectionChanged event.

Comment: Ok, I thought there was how to do this in the entity framework. For example, the entity framework could have a way to not run the setters and CollectionChanged events, when the class was loaded from the database.

Comment: when running from EntityFrameWork remove CollectionChanged event .Produtos.CollectionChanged -= ProdutosCollectionChanged;

Comment: the subscription is done in the constructor though. Where would you set the boolean? Could you add a working example?

Comment: public class Orcamento
{
    public Orcamento()
    {
       public static bool IsFromDatabase;
        Produtos = new ObservableCollection<Produto>();
        Produtos.CollectionChanged += ProdutosCollectionChanged;
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ObservableCollection<Produto> Produtos { get; private set; }

    private void ProdutosCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
if(IsFromDatabase)
{
        //Some process here that should not be run if it is being loaded from the database
}
    }

}